# How to retrive field name from selected field in QgsFieldComboBox

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt, combo-box

I want to read the field name as string format from a `QgsFieldComboBox`.
How to read?

I tried like following but not working for some comparison.

```
selectedField = self.dlg.QgsFieldcomboBox.currentField
```

Comment: what did you put into the comboBox? We need to see more code than just this line to be able to help you

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: It's `currentField()` with params! Otherwise you don't call the method. This will return a string.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `currentField` without `()` you get the method itself, you don't call the method. Use `selectedField = self.dlg.QgsFieldcomboBox.currentField()`.

[currentField()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFieldComboBox.html#a8a79b5c9210f29aa1cff7bee328de04e) returns the field name as string.